# Prevalence rate of thyroid cancer

Tags: cancer, statistics, thyroid, ratio, who-world-health-org

I am looking for the newest information about the global rate of thyroid cancer. I've searched on WHO website, but it didn't work. Please introduce up-to-date, informative resources. Thank you.